# Updating build process from devenv to MSBuild: error allowDefinition='MachineToApplication'

Tags: c#, msbuild, precompile, devenv

I am working with a legacy application. For reasons lost to history, the build process involves using `devenv` not `msbuild` to do the build.

I'm setting up SonarQube using `SonarScanner.MSBuild.exe`. This doesn't seem to capture any info/stats for `devenv` builds (clues in the name I guess) so I'm looking to move to `MSBuild`.

Using `"C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\Bin\MSBuild.exe" solutionname.sln /p:PostBuildEvent= /p:Configuration=Debug /t:Rebuild /m` works on my local development machine to build the solution. However, it fails on our build box with the following error:

> path\webservice project\web.config(5): error ASPCONFIG: It is an error to use a section registered as allowDefinition='MachineToApplication' beyond application level.  This error can be caused by a virtual directory not being configured as an application in IIS. [path\webservice project.metaproj]

Reading the error message, and research online, it appears this may be due to a call to aspnet_compiler using the `-v` switch for a vdir that doesn't exist in IIS.

This would make sense, IIS is configured on my dev machine but not on the build box (because it's a build box not an app server!). Ideally, I'd like to get this building using MSBuild without configuring IIS on the build box (That is an option, but doesn't feel like the 'right' solution to me) and without breaking the current build process (updating that is a much bigger piece of work and will need a lot of testing!)

- The web.config referenced in the error message doesn't have a reference to `allowDefinition`.
- Reading the MSBuild output it looks like the .metaproj is calling `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_compiler.exe -v /localhost_2437 -p path\webservice project\ -u -f -d PrecompiledWeb\localhost_2437\` So this looks like a likely suspect.
- The .metaproj listed in build output doesn't exist, so presumably a temp file created by MSBuild (?)

The parent solution file has the following entry:

```
 Project("{E24C65DC-7377-472B-9ABA-BC803B73C61A}") = "Projecname", "project path\", "{F7F0F1A0-B5BB-4D69-90D1-7E0B6C1B1A63}"
      ProjectSection(WebsiteProperties) = preProject
           TargetFrameworkMoniker = ".NETFramework,Version%3Dv4.6.1"
           Debug.AspNetCompiler.VirtualPath = "/localhost_4102"
           Debug.AspNetCompiler.PhysicalPath = "path\"
           Debug.AspNetCompiler.TargetPath = "PrecompiledWeb\localhost_4102\"
           Debug.AspNetCompiler.Updateable = "true"
           Debug.AspNetCompiler.ForceOverwrite = "true"
           Debug.AspNetCompiler.FixedNames = "false"
           Debug.AspNetCompiler.Debug = "True"
           VWDPort = "4102"
           SlnRelativePath = "path\"
      EndProjectSection
      ProjectSection(ProjectDependencies) = postProject
           ...snip...
      EndProjectSection
 EndProject
```

So it looks like we have some precompilation settings here, which is whats making it call to aspnet_compiler.exe with the -v setting that is causing MSBuild to error.

I've not really had a lot of experience with the website project type or precompilation. Is there a way I can switch off the precompilation for MSBuild  without changing the behaviour of the current devenv build process?

Comment: what happens if you delete that solution and create a new solution file from scratch? (i.e. one without that preProject section).

Comment: When I add the existing website to the solution it creates the `preProject` section identical to the one in my existing sln

Comment: My short term workaround is to copy the solution, remove the website projects and use this solution for msbuild. It misses some of the projects but 80% is better than 0%